# FK_JobDetails_StokCards_StokCardID' on table 'JobDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 3 tables on my database

StokCard,Job and JobDetail

Job Table goes :

```
public JobTypesEnum JobType { get; set; }
public DateTime JobDate { get; set; }
public int StokCardID { get; set; }
public StokCard StokCard { get; set; }
public decimal JobQuantity { get; set; }
public decimal CompleteQuantity { get; set; }
public decimal ScrapQuantity { get; set; }
public bool Status { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public List<JobDetail> JobDetails { get; set; }
```

JobDetail Table goes :

```
public int JobID { get; set; }
public Job Job { get; set; }
public int OperationID { get; set; }
public Operation Operation { get; set; }
public int StokCardID { get; set; }
public StokCard StokCard { get; set; }
public decimal QuantityRequired { get; set; }
```

And StokCard tables goes :

```
.................. // other properties
public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
public List<JobDetail> JobDetails { get; set; }
```

I am getting this error :

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_JobDetails_StokCards_StokCardID' on table 'JobDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I try these but I think something is missing or I should write one more would you mind please help ?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StokCard>()
   .HasMany(o => o.JobDetails)
   .WithOne(m => m.StokCard)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```